# Libreoffice Writer got me bad_alloc alert and then crashed in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, libreoffice, crash

My "Libreoffice Writer" got me this alert and then crashed.

So What it means?

[image]

My memory is **2G**.

My Ubuntu **15.04 64Bit**.

Isn't my memory enough for this version of Ubuntu or this error refers to other reasons?

Comment: I have the sam problem with libreoffice 5.0.1.2 on ubuntu with xfce (but libs for gnome and kde are installed). If i first start libreoffice writer, libroffice will crash with the std::bad_alloc - errormessage. If i first start libreoffice calc, libroffice will work - include writer. I have deleted the dir $HOME/.config/libreoffice/ with the settings and stuff for libreoffice4 but this was not helpfuell, (th dir was recreated on next start) the error is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Solved for me.

I have removed all libreoffice stuff with synaptic and then the libreoffice newly installed.

Selected packets:
`libreoffice5 (1:5.01.1~rc2-0ubuntu~trusty1)` and `libreoffice-help-de`

synaptic/apt select the other stuff (`libreoffice-l10n` ...).

Tried.

Then i have installed step by step the tools i need (script-provider, writer2latex, ...).

Work now for me without the Errors. I think there was incompatible stuff on the system. Try the same steps.

Comment: Actually this error refers to my memory. I had 2G Ram and it makes this problem . After upgrading my Ram to 8G this problem disappeared.